# Is it still possible to anonymize the user's IP in Google Analytics 4 (GA4)?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

In Google Analytics v3 it was possible to anonymize the user's IP address using

```
{ anonymize_ip: true }
```

On the official GA4 page I can't find any information about it and some turorials suggest to still use it like this with Google Analytics 4:

```
gtag('config', 'G-1234568790', { anonymize_ip: true });
```

While it's possible to add this parameter here, I don't know whether it actaully does what I think it should. Because the paremter now shows up in the tracking of every event:

[image]

Does it still anonymize the IP? If not: What is the correct way to anonymize the user's IP in GA4?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it. Lots of folks are using VPNs these days. Some browsers like Brave, Mozilla, and Opera even have VPN support built in. IP addresses will probably end up being redundant in the world of analytics by the end of the decade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Google Analytics 4 properties, IP anonymization is enabled by default.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2763052?hl=en

> Google Analytics 4 (collect data from your apps and/or your website): IP-address anonymization is always enabled. With this option, you collect data from your apps using the Firebase SDKs, and collect data from your website using a global site tag that includes a Measurement ID for your web data stream.

Other link: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9019185#IP&zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was on this page before, but missed this totally.

Comment: That link doesn't have the quoted text any longer. I found something like it here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9019185#IP